# How-to chain and apply a stream of comparators?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of unsorted items and a stream of comparators.
I want to apply all the comparators onto the stream by using "thenComparing" (Multisort)
Is there a more elegant way than the following code to achive this?

```
Stream unsorted = ...;
Stream<Comparator> comparators = ...;

Comparator compareFunc = comparators.reduce(null, (a, b) -> {
        if(a == null) {
            return b;
        }else {
            return  a.thenComparing(b); 
        }

    });

Stream result = unsorted.sorted(compareFunc);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid the reduce null parameter and the if (a==null) statement

Comment: It'd probably be slightly cleaner if you used a base comparator  that always returns 0 instead of `null`.  That'd remove the null and the branch.

Comment: @mark yep that simplifies the code compareFunc = comparators.reduce((a, b ) -> 0, (a, b) -> 
              a.thenComparing(b)); thanxs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don’t use an *identity value* for `Comparator`s. If the `comparators` stream is empty (i.e. does not contain any `Comparator`) you should not sort:

```
Stream result=comparators.reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
             .map(unsorted::sorted).orElse(unsorted);
```

Note that if the `comparators` stream contains only a single `Comparator`, that `Comparator` will be the result of the reduction.

---

The method reference passed to `Optional.map` might need some experience to get used to it. So it might be worth using the more verbose lambda syntax to show what’s going on there:

```
Stream<String> result=comparators.reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
    .map((comparator) -> unsorted.sorted(comparator)).orElse(unsorted);
```

That’s a matter of programming style or personal preference and might change over time.

Comment: thanxs so much looks nice

Answer (score 6):

Using Mark Peters' suggestion and mixing it with a method reference, you could write your comparator this way:

```
Comparator compareFunc = comparators.reduce((a, b) -> 0, Comparator::thenComparing);
```

Or stealing a bit from Holger instead:

```
Optional<Comparator> compareFunc = comparators.reduce(Comparator::thenComparing);
Stream<?> result = compareFunc.isPresent() ? result.sorted(compareFunc.get())
                                           : unsorted;
```

Comment: @Holger I stole a bit of your idea - I find the inverted syntax of your answer less clear to be honest.

Comment: Well, I prefer telling the `Optional` what to do over using `isPresent()`. That’s closer to what you do with `Stream`s vs. external iteration. But, of course, the external operation expresses more (is more verbose about) what’s going on…