# Sort a list of objects based on an unknown number of keys

Tags: java, java-8

I've seen plenty of ways to sort a list of objects that work fine if you know the incoming keys or at least the incoming number of keys.
Problem is in my case I don't know if the user will send in 1 or 10 keys.

Currently I have a giant switch statements for each number of keys, but obviously that scales terribly. It just chains a bunch of 'thenComparing' together.

I found an example here that looks like it kind of helps but I don't know how to build a stream of comparators.

[How-to chain and apply a stream of comparators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25850008/how-to-chain-and-apply-a-stream-of-comparators)

Looking for a link or really anything pieces of information that will fill in the gaps on how to do this.

This all works from a user calling webservice where they would call it like

```
https://host.com/path?sort=[{"attribute1": "ASC"}, {"attribute2": "DESC"}]
```

Comment: What is the determining factor for the sorting? Like for example, how would these items be sorted: "A", "B",  "ABC", "BC"?

Comment: How does the user tell your code what the keys are?

Comment: They pass in an object as a param like [{"attribute1": "ASC"}, {"attribute2": "DESC"}]

Comment: You do know that `Comparator<Foo> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Foo::getA).thenComparing(Foo::getB).thenComparing(Foo::getC);` is the same as `Comparator<Foo> cmp = Comparator.comparing(Foo::getA); cmp = cmp.thenComparing(Foo::getB); cmp = cmp.thenComparing(Foo::getC);`, which is easy to do in a loop, right?

Comment: Fair point @Andreas . Can Food and getA/getC be defined from variables instead of hard coded?

Comment: You have to give a `compare()` method or lambda for comparing the attribute in question. Since we don't know how your data is stored, how do you expect us to help you with that?

Comment: @Andreas you are right in general, the problem is to get those fields to a `Function` (I assume those could be `int`, `String`, etc)... initially I thought about `Map<String, Function<Person, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", Person::getName);` and based on the key get the `Function` that is to be supplied to `Comparator.comparing`, but that would work for String only properties

Comment: @Andreas I have written a custom comparer for handling that (checks the type and compares appropriately depending on what it sees). I was more focused on the looping part and less on the how to actually make sure it's comparing correctly.

Comment: @Eugene why not use a Function<Foo, ? extends Object> as the map value

Comment: If your custom comparer can compare one attribute, then what I showed you can be used to chain multiple instances of that comparer together, using a loop.

Comment: I think you are correct and I plan on trying it out. Logically it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Hope you don't pull the objects from a database. ;) But since you are talking about sorting by up to 10 attributes, it sounds like a large number of objects...

Comment: We pull data from a database, map them into objects in a list. And then try and sort the list before returning.

Comment: @Lino even simpler :) but you gave the `aha moment`, thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose you have such an entity:

```
static class Person {
    private final int age;

    private final String name;

    public Person(int age, String name) {
        this.age = age;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

You could define all the fields and map those to a certain comparator:

```
Map<String, Comparator<Person>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("name_ASC", Comparator.comparing(Person::getName));
map.put("name_DESC", Comparator.comparing(Person::getName).reversed());

map.put("age_ASC", Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge));
map.put("age_DESC", Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge).reversed());
```

And then having your input, you could do:

```
Comparator<Person> all = Stream.of("name_ASC", "age_DESC") // for example
            .map(map::get)
            .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
            .orElse((a, b) -> 0); // or whatever you think appropriate
```

And sorting them after this is obviously a no brainer:

```
 List<Person> persons = List.of(new Person(20, "Bob"), new Person(30, "Rose"));

 // or Collections.sort(persons, all)
 // persons.sort(all)
 persons.stream().sorted(all).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This makes it pretty clear. I'll probably end up accepting this, just want to hack something similar into place. Thanks for all the comments and answer!

Comment: Great answer +1, and if one doesn't care about the inital list, then `persons.sort(all)` will suffice

Comment: Works too, that would keep the `persons` immutable, so I guess it will depend on the situation

Answer (score 1):

if you can build a list of comparators, you could use something like this:

```
public class MultiComparator<T> implements Comparator<T> {

    private final List<Comparator<T>> comparators;

    MultiComparator(List<Comparator<T>> comparators){
        this.comparators = comparators;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(T t1, T t2) {
        int r = 0;
        for(Comparator c : comparators){
            r = c.compare(t1,t2);
            if(r != 0){
                return r;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

}
```

(not very java 8 ish though)